# What is the correct file format for a logo?

Tags: logo, resize, file-format, eps

I had my logo professionally made and when finished they gave me a series of files of different types. One of those was to be able to enlarge the logo without distortion or pixelation. I think it was `.eps` but I have forgotten.

Is `.eps` the file format that allows a logo to be infinitely scalable?

Comment: Ask your profesionist designer. But yes, an eps is probably the one. Others are PDF, AI, CDR.

Comment: @Rafael Please refrain from answering questions in the comments--make them an answer, no matter how short. Well, beyond the character limit, that is ;)

Comment: I had the feeling the question would be closed faster than a click of a mouse. XD

Answer (score 1):

Ask your profesional designer.

But yes, the EPS is probably the one. Others are PDF, AI, CDR.

Enlargin a  logo "without distortion" could have a wide range of flavors. Normally the user is the one that distorts a logo. (The question was edited adding the word pixelation, which makes it more especific)

---

Some explanations.

The formats I mentioned are capable of having inside vector information, this is the thing you are looking for. This vectors can be resized and mantain sharp edges, but only if they are prepared correctly.

*Just keep in mind...*
But they can have inside also a bitmap image, in that case they wont be as usefull as it should be. This bitmap images can be pixelated when enlarged.

Other common formats designers deliver a logo are PNG, PSD, which can be pixelated in most cases, when enlarging.

Comment: All OP said was "to enlarge the logo without distortion or pixelation", nothing about manipulating the logo—that's exactly why you give a vector version of a logo.

Comment: (Pixelation was added later by Vincent) ;o) (Oh, and enlarging it is a form of manipulation)

Comment: Fair enough :) Still, I think OP just wants to use the logo without worrying about specific sizes, nothing more.